# In describing a shocking/earth-shattering novel idea, is there a phrase that resembles "Breaks the roof"?

Tags: text

I have seen some sefarim (books) from the past couple centuries discuss and review other people's opinions and interpretations, and describe the wild/hard to believe mahalchim (opinions) as being הפלא ופלא (wondrous?) and other phrases. (Afterwards the author proceeds with his own approach.) Sometimes understanding these narrative signposts can help you feel out where the author is heading towards in relation to the opinion portrayed.

Is there a phrase that scholars use that resembles, "breaks the roof". I vaguely recall hearing something like merafsa igra, but maybe I'm way off.

Can someone please reply if they know of the phrase that is used in this way, and/or if there are references to where books write this phrase?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

מרפסין אגרי is the phrase, from [Kid. 63b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.63b.12?with=all&lang=bi).

[This list from Sefaria's search](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%90&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) might help you.

Comment: @Oliver - Thank you for the edit.

Comment: Sure thing (15)